# Building a Word Counter for Analysis

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

I'm trying to build a Python program similar to the wordcounter.net (https://wordcounter.net/).
I have an excel file with one column that has text to be analyzed. Using pandas and other functions, I created a single word frequency counter.

But now, I need to further modify to find patterns.

For example a text has " Happy face sad face mellow little baby sweet
Happy face face mellow sad face mellow "

So here, it should be able to trace patterns such as
**Two word density**

- **Pattern**       **Count**
- "Happy face"        2
- "sad face"         2
- "face mellow"       3

....

**Three word density**

- **Pattern**             **Count**
- "Happy face sad"       1
- "face sad face"        1

....

I also tried :

```
for match in re.finditer(pattern, line):
```

But this again has to be done manually and I want it to automatically find the patterns.

Can anyone help on how to proceed for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
text = 'Happy face sad face mellow little baby sweet Happy face face mellow sad face mellow'

d = {}
for s in text.split():
    d.setdefault(s, 0)
    d[s] += 1
out = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    out.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
for i in sorted(out.keys(), reverse=True):
    print(f'{i} word density:')
    print(f'\t{out[i]}')
```

**Output**

```
5 word density:
    ['face']
3 word density:
    ['mellow']
2 word density:
    ['Happy', 'sad']
1 word density:
    ['little', 'baby', 'sweet']
```

### Edit2

```
from collections import Counter


def freq(lst, n):
    lstn = []
    for i in range(len(lst) - (n - 1)):
        lstn.append(" ".join([lst[i + x] for x in range(n)]))
    out = Counter(lstn)
    print(f'{n} word density:')
    for k, v in out.items():
        print(f'\t"{k}" {v}')


text = 'Happy face sad face mellow little baby sweet Happy face face mellow sad face mellow'
lst = text.split()

freq(lst, 2)
freq(lst, 3)
```

**Output**

```
2 word density:
    "Happy face" 2
    "face sad" 1
    "sad face" 2
    "face mellow" 3
    "mellow little" 1
    "little baby" 1
    "baby sweet" 1
    "sweet Happy" 1
    "face face" 1
    "mellow sad" 1
3 word density:
    "Happy face sad" 1
    "face sad face" 1
    "sad face mellow" 2
    "face mellow little" 1
    "mellow little baby" 1
    "little baby sweet" 1
    "baby sweet Happy" 1
    "sweet Happy face" 1
    "Happy face face" 1
    "face face mellow" 1
    "face mellow sad" 1
    "mellow sad face" 1
```

Comment: Hey thanks for trying out. I have this single frequency counter. I need to expand it like searching for "happy face", " sad face"  in the text and get a count for that. Maybe I'll edit the question to make it more clear. Really appreciate your effort.

Comment: see Edit2 version

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. This really solved my problem. 

Would like to ask one more thing. How can we save these outputs in csv or excel ?

Comment: @MitaliPatel There are a lot of similar questions and answers here. Try searching, for example, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+save+dictionary+to+csv